# How to save Data while using android webview

Tags: android

I am trying to make a web browser for android (android application), but the thing is that when it opens webpages in web-view, its consumes too much of data... Is there a way in which I can reduce it? For example: By not displaying images...?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkImage%28boolean%29

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
```

This'll ensure that images are not loaded from the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can using this method.

```
   webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
```

for your information:
  if you are targeting api level 8 (2.2) or higher you can using this
 generally to load faster.

```
   webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(true);
```